# Command to test if system is Windows or Unix

Tags: windows, unix, shell, c++

I'm looking for a shell command in unix that has a non zero output that is uniform across all unix platforms (for example will allways return 1 on a unix system) and also has no (or zero value) output in windows.

I tried (in unix):

```
sh echo 1
```

but this returns:

```
cannot execute binary file
```

using

```
echo 1
```

would not fit this criteria since it produces an output in windows as well as unix.

Comment: `uname` seems to work on a lot of systems. Example: # uname -> FreeBSD. On another computer: #uname -> Linux

Comment: on windows xp: 'uname' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: and strangely enough, my mac returned "Darwin"... haha

Comment: It should. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname :)

Comment: Basically you could use it to identify a OS/X, Linux (generally) , Debian (specifically this distribution), FreeBSD, Irix, Haiku, AIX, windows with cigwin and Minix. Failure to start could be used as 'windows or other OS'

Comment: This seems to ask two different questions.  Based on the title of this question.  Do you want to test to see if what kind or type of system it is being ran on, or are you trying to get exit codes from commands on Windows like you do on Mac, BSD, Linux, Unix?

Comment: The absence of `uname` does not mean that the system is not a Unix or Unix-like system.  MinGW includes a working `uname` for Windows.  On my Windows 7 system with MinGW, `uname` returns `MINGW32_NT-6.1`.

Comment: @vgoff: neither. I'm looking for a unix command that produces a non-zero deterministic return value (preferably 1), that will not function and will produce no return value (save warnings) in a windows system.

Comment: @Hennes: uname would work, but unfortunately I need it to produce the same result regardless of which unix based operating system the command is called on.

Comment: A return value is different than output.  But I see.  I am will have to sleep on it, I know nothing off hand that will do this.  Could you write one?

Comment: What language are you programming with?

Comment: c++, I'm gonna add that above.

Comment: Using `uname` isn't ideal, as some pairs of distantly-related operating systems (OS X and Darwin, Windows 7 and OS/2 Warp, etc.) could be completely indistinguishable.

Comment: The question is really vague. Which shell are you going to run this in Windows? Cygwin/Msys, WSL bash, PowerShell, cmd? Is it in a script? Why do you run `sh echo 1`? There's no sh in Windows cmd

Comment: Why is C++ relevant here? You don't write native binaries that run everywhere, so in C++ you can just check at compile time. Linux executables obviously can't run on Windows so there's no need to check

Answer (score 3):

The `dir` command exists in both Linux and Windows and may be suitable for this.  The `dir` command on windows does set the exit code for scripting.  It also has a plus, in that it is a non-destructive command.

On Linux, according to the man pages these error codes are available.

```
Exit status:
 0  if OK,
 1  if minor problems (e.g., cannot access subdirectory),
 2  if serious trouble (e.g., cannot access command-line argument).
```

Comment: Really thanks to [Joey](http://superuser.com/users/2054/joey) for helping me flush this out, as I really went on a tangent.

Comment: I wonder if using the information [verifying the system version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725491(VS.85).aspx_ "MSDN") would help.  Write a C++ Program to do 'absolutely nothing but fail' if it is on Windows.  And write a portion that will return otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Test for the existence of the `SYSTEMROOT` or `SYSTEMDRIVE` environment variables to confirm you're on Windows.  If you insist on a real belt-and-suspenders approach, parse the value to confirm you find a `C:` or similar drive letter.

Comment: but on Windows cmd you use `%SYSTEMROOT%` which doesn't work on Unix shells

Comment: Use the env command to dump the environment variables.  It exists on both Unix/Linux and Windows.

Comment: There's no `env` command in Windows. You use `set` instead. Moreover even if you manage somehow to get the environment variables list then there's no common way to check if a word exists in that list or not. In Windows you use `find(str)` whereas in Unix you use `grep`

Comment: Apologies, you're correct.  When I checked cmd.exe, I didn't realize I had my own utils in the search path.  Indeed, one should use the set command; it exists in both cmd.exe and bash.